# Xamarin InAppBilling

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, in-app-billing

I have a xamarin application with in app billing feature using the nuget package from James Montenegro. When user is uses the app for the first time, after a few hours, the user access to the app pages should be blocked

For example using is in page 1, after a some minutes or an hour, a page should be displayed to the user automatically with a button for user to pay to continue using the app. When user quit and reopen the app, the page asking user to pay should still be displayed if user haven't subscribed. Can you help me with this please. Thanks

Comment: What is your question?  What **specifically** are you stuck on or need help with?  Your post is just a vaguely stated list of requirements, not an actual question.

Comment: Is more like a feature I'm trying to  implement. Block access to a page using another page that have a button asking the user to pay

Comment: I understand, but it's so incredibly vague that it's impossible to answer.  A more focused question might be "how do I track how much total time a user has spent in my app?"

Comment: OK I may not have asked that correctly but the main things I'm trying to achieve is to block access to a page if user is yet to subscribe. That's just it

Comment: whatever action the user takes to get to `PageX`, check if they are allowed to access it before navigating.  If they are not, display an error message instead of navigating.  Again, I have no idea how your app is designed or what kind of navigation you are using, so I can't provide any more specific advice.